# Javascript variable value doesn't change once after page loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I initialize a property within the Controller's Constructor.

```
public MyController()
{
  SessionProvider.IntializeMethod = false;
}
```

I have an Action Method which reset the property again on a button click event.

```
public ActionResult Initialize(int Id)
{
  SessionProvider.IntializeMethod  = true;
  // remaining code
  return Json(Id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Following javascript code is in my view which is called when the button is clicked.

```
var MyHandler = {
  $("#btnInit").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("Initialize", "My")",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'Id': MyHandler.getItemId()
      },
      success: function (response) {
        var Id = response;
        var isInitilize = "@MyProject.Presentation.MVC.App_Start.SessionProvider.IntializeMethod ";
        // code
        window.open("@Url.Action("Index", "OtherPage", new {Initialize = "_initialize"}).replace('_initialize', isInitilize ), tabId);
      },
      error: function () {
        //
      }
    });
  });
}
```

My problem is when I click the button, value of property  changes in the Controller. But it doesn't change in my javascript code.Please see the screen capture of the developer tool.

does Anyone has a clue on this?

Comment: It should not change. because it is already written when View is loaded.. `var isInitilize = "@MyProject.Presentation.MVC.App_Start.SessionProvider.IntializeMethod ";` This will be declared at rendering of view and it will not be changed..

Comment: `var isInitilize = "@MyProject.....` is razor code. It is parsed on the server before it is sent to the view. You need to send the modified value back in response

Comment: Backend (Server side) Languages are executed only ones when a page is loading. I will suggest get data in javascript variable  or hidden input while document load.

Answer (score 0):

It should not change. because it is already written when View is loaded..

`var isInitilize = "@MyProject.Presentation.MVC.App_Start.SessionProvider.IntializeMethod ";`

This will be declared at rendering of view and it will not be changed.. If you want the updated value from your action then you should return that as JSON (as you are using *jquery ajax* for calling the *Controller's Action*).

As per your explanation, you should use something like :

```
public ActionResult Initialize(int Id)
{
  SessionProvider.IntializeMethod  = true;
  // remaining code
  return Json(new { Id = 1, Name = "Sachin" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   ////I changed here ////
  //return Json(Id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

whereas you can get that in javascript like :

```
var MyHandler = {
  $("#btnInit").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("Initialize", "My")",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'Id': MyHandler.getItemId()
      },
      success: function (response) {
        var Id = response.Id;            ////I changed here ////
        var isInitilize = response.Name; ////I changed here ////

        // code
        window.open("@Url.Action("Index", "OtherPage", new {Initialize = "_initialize"}).replace('_initialize', isInitilize ), tabId);
      },
      error: function () {
        //
      }
    });
  });
}
```

If I were you then I should return the URL of action like 
`return Json(new { Id = 1, URL = "/controller/action/param" })`.

Comment: Do I need to return SessionProvider.IntializeMethod in My response ?

Comment: first you have to explain your requirement.. I have seen in your code you are opening new window/page but not using `isInitilize` or 'Id'.. You should pass both `Id` and 'SessionProvider.IntializeMethod' in a single json object

Comment: confused in : `window.open("@Url.Action("Index", "OtherPage", new {Initialize = "_initialize"}).replace('_initialize', isInitilize ), tabId); what is tabId & you want to redirect to another action? can you provide a sample URL like "/OtherPage/Index/101" ?

Comment: Yes I need to redirect to another action.  end of the action method will open a tab in browser. tabId is a random number, in order to create a separate tab rather than opening in the same tab.